# Finding the mean sales price

Tags: probability, random-variables

everyone.

I have the following problem: a factory produce valves, with 20% chance of a given valve be broken. The valves are sold in boxes, containing ten valves in each box. If no broken valve is found, then they sell the box for 10 dollars. With one broken valve, the box costs 8 dollars. With two or three, the box is sold for $6.00. More than three valves broken, they sell the box for 2 dollars. What is the mean sales price for the boxes?

I calculated the chances of getting a box with no broken valves, the chances of getting a box with 9 normal valves and 1 broken, the chances of getting a box with 8 normal valves and 2 broken and so on.

Then, I calculated the mean of the probabilities but got stuck in this part. How can I proceed? Or is there a better way to solve it?

Thanks you.

Comment: What do mean by "the mean of the probabilities"?  Perhaps you could show us your calculations instead of describing them.

Comment: Hint: Think of expected value. Multiply the probability by the price for each case, and try to find the mean from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there.

For the probabilities, I am assuming you got it correct and got

$10.7374\%$ chance of $0$ broken,

$26.8435\%$ chance of $1$ broken,

$30.199\%$ chance of $2$ broken,

$20.1327\%$ chance of $3$ broken, and

$12.0874\%$ chance of more than $3$ broken.

Now, all we have to do is multiply the probabilities by the price and add them all up to get the mean price. More explanation coming, but for now...

$10.7374\%\cdot 10=\$1.07374$. This is just the probability of $0$ valves broken multiplied by the price, $\$10$.

Similarly, $26.8435\%\cdot 8=\$2.14748$.

For $2$ valves, it's $\$1.81194$ and for $3$ valves, it's $\$1.207962$.

Finally, for $4$ or more valves, it's $12.0874\%\cdot 2=\$0.241748$.

Adding all the values up our answer is simply

$1.07374+2.14748+1.207962+1.88194+0.241748=\fbox{\$6.55287}$.

You may be asking, "**But *why* is all we need to do add the values? Since it's a mean, don't we have to divide by something?**

We already did. We already divided when computing the probability. Let's take a simple example.

Let's shorten this problem down to simple terms: Let's say there are packs of 3 valves, where $50\%$ of the time the valves are broken. If none are broken, they are sold for $\$5$, while for $1, 2, \text { and } 3$ valves broken, they sell for $\$4, \$3, \text { and } \$2$ dollars, respectively.

We can see that the mean will probably be $\$3.50$, since there's a $50\%$ broken rate and  the cost ranges from $5$ to $2$, and the middle of that is $3.50$. Let's calculate using how we did above.

The probability of none breaking is $\frac{1}{8}$ so multiplying by $5$ gets us a $\$\frac{5}{8}$ths probability.

Similarly, the next is a $\frac{3}{8}$ths chance so multiplying by $4$ gets us a $\$\frac{3}{2}$ value.

The next two get us $\$\frac{9}{8}$ and $\$\frac{1}{4}$, respectively.

Adding up gets us $\frac{7}{2}$, or $\$3.50$ as our answer. Just as we expected!

This happens because, again, we already divided for our probability. If we calculated the number of *ways* $5, 4, 3, \text{ and } 2$ dollars could be computed, then we would have to divide by $8$. But we already divided to get our probability so there is no need to divide again.

Therefore, our answer is $\fbox{\$6.55287}$, or if we round, $\fbox{\$6.55}$.

-FruDe

Comment: Thank you a lot, it was really helpful. I would just like to ask if you could share how you calculated the probabilities of getting the broken valves. For example, when calculating the probability of getting 8 normal valves and 2 broken, I calculated as $P(\dfrac{4}{5})^8 * P(\dfrac{1}{5})^2 = 0.0067$ (4/5 being the probability of getting a normal valve and 1/5 of getting a broken one) which would be 0,67%.

Comment: @matcher2020 Your logic is mostly right, but you can also order the way the probability occurs. If we let B be broken valves and F be fixed valves you can have BFBFFFFFFF and BFFBFFFFF. Therefore, you have to multiply 10 choose 2 to your answer, since you can choose 2 out of any 10 and order them. Take a simple case like the probability of getting one head and one tail when flipping two coins. It's actually 1/2, not 1/4. This is because you have to multiply by 2 choose 1 at the end. Hope that helped :)